# Ping multiple ips and write to JSON file python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, multiprocessing, subprocess

I am pinging multiple ips in the LAN to check if it is alive or not. the code will be run every minute based on schedule.For pinging multiple ips, i used multiprocessing. It is done great with the help of multiprocessing. Simultaneously, i want to write the ping results to the json file after pinging. But When writing to the JSON file, it is writing only the output of the last ip.I want all the three.
Is there any way to do this

Here's the sample Code:

```
import json
from multiprocessing import Pool
import subprocess
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S")
hosts =  ["192.168.1.47","192.168.1.42"]
count = 1
wait_sec = 1
n = len(hosts)
def main(hosts):
    p = Pool(processes= n)
    result = p.map(beat, hosts)
def beat(hosts):
    #Name for the log file
    name = 'icmp.json'
    ip4write(hosts, name)
def ip4write(hosts, name):
    global ip4a
    ip4a = hosts
    ipve4(hosts, name)
    write(hosts, name)
def ipve4(hosts, name):
    global u
    status, result = subprocess.getstatusoutput("ping -c1 -w2 " + str(ip4a))
    if status == 0:
        print(str(ip4a) + " UP")
        u = " UP"
def write(hosts, name):
    text_file = open(name, "a+")
    with open(name) as json_file:
      try:
          data = json.load(json_file)
      except:
          data = {}
      with open(name, 'w') as outfile:
        data[timestamp] = {
          'monitor.ip':str(hosts),
          'monitor.status': u
        }
        print(data)
        json.dump(data, outfile)
        print('Data written')
    text_file.close()
main(hosts)
```

Output in JSON file:

```
{"February 15 2019, 16:38:12": {"monitor.status": " UP", "monitor.ip": "192.168.1.42"}}
```

My required Output:

```
{"February 15 2019, 16:38:12": {"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.47", "monitor.status": " UP"}, "February 15 2019, 16:38:12": {"monitor.ip": "192.168.1.42", "monitor.status": " UP"}}
```

Comment: I know this sounds kind a weird but you can write data to a mongodb database instead of writing it to a json and then export that database into a json file ?

Comment: I think your monitoring solution will scale much better  if you will go and use sqlite instead of JSON file. Just create a simple table (Fields: timestamp,host,status) and insert the data to this table. See here how to do it: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-python/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Below is a compact version of the code:

```
import os
from multiprocessing import Pool
import json
import datetime
import time

hosts = ["192.168.1.47", "8.8.8.8"]
MAX_NUMBER_OF_STATUS_CHECKS = 2
FILE_NAME = 'hosts_stats.json'


#
# counter and sleep were added in order to simulate scheduler activity  
#

def ping(host):
    status = os.system('ping  -o -c 3 {}'.format(host))
    return datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%B %d %Y, %H:%M:%S"), {"monitor.ip": host,
                                                                "monitor.status": 'UP' if status == 0 else 'DOWN'}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    p = Pool(processes=len(hosts))
    counter = 0
    if not os.path.exists(FILE_NAME):
        with open(FILE_NAME, 'w') as f:
            f.write('{}')
    while counter < MAX_NUMBER_OF_STATUS_CHECKS:
        result = p.map(ping, hosts)
        with open(FILE_NAME, 'rb+') as f:
            f.seek(-1, os.SEEK_END)
            f.truncate()
            for entry in result:
                _entry = '"{}":{},\n'.format(entry[0], json.dumps(entry[1]))
                f.writelines(_entry)
             f.write('}')
        counter += 1
        time.sleep(2)
```

Comment: the code will be run every minute based on schedule. But this code rewrite the whole JSON file

Comment: Paul Steven. Code was modified based on your comment

Comment: But it doesn't become a valid JSON file.

Comment: See my required output

Comment: Paul Steven. Code was modified again. The function load_hosts_stats() was added so the file is loaded into list of dictionaries. This is quite close to the required output I hope.

Comment: First time,it writes the data to the json. Second time,it doesn't write the data within the bracket which makes it a invalid json file. This is the same problem which caused in my code.The link to check valid JSON file [http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ ]

Comment: Does the file needs to be a valid JSON or it can be loaded into a valid python dict? Is this JSON structure mandatory or you can modify it? The simple solution in my eyes is to manage the file where each line represents a stats check and it is a valid JSON. This way appending should be easy. Once it needs to be loaded into a dict it can be wrapped with [] in order to have list of dicts

Comment: Yes. it needs to be valid JSON file.

Comment: Code wad modified in order to have a valid JSON

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It worked great. But to make it work in python 3,i converted  str to bytes when writing in JSON file. it showing me that "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'. But i checked the type and the type is in bytes. Why it can't take that.  Any idea about that..

Answer (score 0):

To keep adding contents to an existing file without overwriting existing content, you should open in the "append" mode. In your code, you are opening in "write" mode. Which will open the file for writing but will overwrite existing contents.

Specifically, this line in your code:

```py
with open(name, 'w') as outfile:
```

You should change the open mode from write (`'w'`) to append (`'a'`).

```py
with open(name, 'a') as outfile:
```

Let me know if this solves your problem.

Comment: No. it doesn't solve mine.the data should be updated within { } in JSON, But it is appending a new one

Comment: That's because you are not updating it! You're appending a new one:

`
 data[timestamp] = {
          'monitor.ip':str(hosts),
          'monitor.status': u
        }
`

Instead it should be:
`
data[timestamp]['monitor.ip'] = str(hosts)
data[timestamp]['monitor.status'] =  'you value here'
`

Comment: You are also  getting two timestamp keys in your JSON, because they are different timestamp values.

Comment: JSON is not a framing protocol, i.e you cannot append to valid JSON and get valid JSON. But see here: http://ndjson.org/

Comment: data[timestamp]['monitor.ip'] = str(hosts) data[timestamp]['monitor.status'] = 'you value here'  => doesn't solve my problem. Any other solutions..

Comment: @PaulSteven we are here to help you conceptually. Not hand-hold you, and write your code. I was pointing you to the right direction, not giving you code that you can copy-paste. Just saying "doesn't solve my problem" is not going to help. You have to articulate what is the exact problem you are facing and what you've tried, and you think you are doing wrong.

Maybe there are others who can give you code that you can copy-paste (and not understand what its doing) and not care more.